# SharePoint online, MS-Flow and calculated date time column #name issue?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time, ms-flow

I've got a `current staff list` with a `StartDate` (datetime) column and two calculated columns: 'DaysWorkedAt', 'YearsWorkedAt'

I have an MS Flow workflow attached to the `new employee list` on `new item created`, it adds an entry to this list and performs the appropriate work adversaries calculation for the 2 columns mentioned above.

My formula for the calculated 'DaysAtCompany' is this:

`=DATEDIF(StartDate,NOW(),"d")`

***Problem I have:***

Adding a new entry via the interface to the `current staff list` the calculation works.

Adding it via the new employee list through MS Flow the calculated columns has a value of `#Name?`

I can't seem to work out what is causing this or how to fix it. I am using the internal names correctly. I can't find any special characters getting inserted.

Attached an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: The date field in first column is blank. whats that field? is it causing this issue?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Nah that just a string column for Birthday that typed in without the year. If you look at the other record they are all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause. It is because the `StartDate` is greater than `Now()`.

[image]

You can use the following formula instead:

For days:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")-StartDate
```

For years:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy")-TEXT(StartDate,"yyyy")
```

[image]

Comment: I also found the same article about the DATE DIF, I've worked error logic into it now. Thanks though, I'll mark your answer as correct.